# Is UV mapping and texturing necessary? Can I just use materials before rigging?

Tags: texturing, uv

Brand new to Blender. I've modeled my first character and added materials to give her color. In my research I've found that UV mapping and Texturing is generally the next step. If I'm happy with the coloring that materials gave, can I skip this step and go straight to rigging? 
Is UV mapping and texturing just to give it an added sense of realism, since materials give it a cartoony shine?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't fix what isn't broken. Or "translated" to what you're asking, if you're happy with what you have, don't change it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to texture a character before you rig it and you don't have to UV unwrap it if a procedural texture works.

While a UV wrapped texture can be used to control the glossy factor in precise parts of the character, you can turn down the overall glossiness of a procedural texture, the steps will depend on which render engine you use and the material you have.

I think it is better to rig a character before unwrapping (especially when learning) as the rigging process can lead to finding bad mesh deforms that need better topology to fix, this leads to an existing UV unwrap needing to be adjusted for the changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are no actual steps you have to follow. You can rig the model first and then do the UV Mapping and Texturing or even assign Materials after Rigging.
If you are scared that you will mess up your model after Rigging you should create sort of a backup like before you did the Rigging so you'd have 2 models at the end:
**"model_rigged"** and **"model_unrigged"**
Also Texturing and UV Mapping isn't only for realism, you can make cartoony textures but you don't have to do it